# How to merge pandas data frames where they are duplicates of the key

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I want to do a special merge, but I'm not sure how to do it in pandas.

I have the following **df1**:

```
    CompanyName      Country Ticker  Revenue ....................
0   Apple Inc.       US      
1   Microsoft        US      MSFT    1235        
2   Sony             US 
3   DBS              SG      D05     5523 
4   Razer            HK      0700.HK 2231
5   General Electric US      GE      2131
6   Check Point      L 
7   Huawei           CN
```

And I have this frame **tickersdf**:

```
    CompanyName       Ticker    Country
0   Apple Inc.        AAPL.MX   MX
1.  Apple Inc.        APC.DE    DE
2.  Apple Inc.        APC.F     F
3.  Microsoft         MSFT      US
4.  Sony              SNE       US
5   Razer             0700.HK   HK
6.  General Electric  GE        US
7.  Sony              6758.T    T
8.  Microsoft         MSFT.BA   BA
9   General Motors.   GM        US
10. Check Point       CHKP      US
```

Firstly, I want to merge on the CompanyName and Country as the keys.

This I would do with a simple command like,

```
df1 = pd.merge(df1,tickersdf,on=['CompanyName','Country'], how='left')
```

So Sony which is missing SNE will be filled up first.

```
    CompanyName      Country Ticker  Revenue ....................
0   Apple Inc.       US      
1   Microsoft        US      MSFT    1235        
2   Sony             US      SNE
3   DBS              SG      D05     5523 
4   Razer            HK      0700.HK 2231
5   General Electric US      GE      2131
6   Check Point      L   
7   Huawei           CN
```

As you can see, **df1** has missing values and I want to get the values from **tickersdf**.

However, **tickersdf** has multiple ticker values for the same CompanyName.

If you look at Apple Inc., it doesn't have the US ticker available, but it has alternatives.

I would like to merge the following data frames like so that I get the following:

```
    CompanyName      Country Ticker    Revenue  ....................
0.  Apple Inc.       US      hasalt
1   Apple Inc.       MX      AAPL.MX    
2.  Apple Inc.       DE      APC.DE
3.  Apple Inc.       F       APC.F
4   Microsoft        US      MSFT      1235
5.  Microsoft        BA      MSFT.BA
6   Sony             US      SNE
7.  Sony             T       6758.T
8   DBS              SG      D05       5523
9   Razer            HK      0700.HK   2231
10  General Electric US      GE        2131
11. Check Point      L       hasalt
12. Check Point      US      CHKP
13. Huawei           CN
```

I don't want to touch the rows that contain a Ticker already in **df1**.

For companies like Apple Inc. and Check Point in this example, the ticker isn't available in US or L, but, it has alternatives. So I want the ticker portion to say 'hasalt' or be left blank and I want the alternatives to be copied over into df1.

Microsoft and Sony already have MSFT and SNE filled in **df1**, however there are alternatives available, so I want those to be checked and copied over to **df1** as well.

If a company name doesn't exist in **df1**, I don't want it to be added on, like General Motors wasn't in **df1**, so I don't want it to be brought over.

Companies like Huawei have no matches at all in the **tickersdf**, so I want it to be left blank.

Can this be done in pandas? If so, how?

I was thinking of doing this

```
df1['Ticker'] = df1['Ticker'].fillna(df1['CompanyName'].map(tickersdf.set_index('CompanyName')['Ticker']))
```

But **tickersdf** has duplicates, then I also considered merging or joining, but I don't think it can be done that way because the entries that are in **tickersdf** that are not in **df1** will appear in **df1**.

I know I can filter out the alternatives using this

```
tickersdf[(tickersdf['CompanyName'].str.contains('Check Point'))]
```

But how do I copy the rows over into df1 based on my condition?

I think it would look something like,

```
if df1['CompanyName'] is in tickersdf['CompanyName'], 

then set df1['Ticker'] = 'hasalt' 

followed by tickersdf[(tickersdf['CompanyName'].str.contains(df1['CompanyName']))] 

and copying all the alternatives over to df1. 

else ignore
```

What's the right way to do this? Could it be done with some kind of special ffill?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the work is made by an outer join... the rest is only filling and rearrange data following your logic

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'CompanyName':['Apple Inc.','Microsoft','Sony','DBS','Razer','General Electric','Check Point','Huawei'],
                    'Country':['US','US','US','SG','HK','US','L','CN'],
                    'Ticker':['','MSFT','','D05','0700.HK','GE','',''],
                    'Revenue':[np.nan,1235,np.nan,5523,2231,2131,np.nan,np.nan]})
tickersdf = pd.DataFrame({'CompanyName':['Apple Inc.','Apple Inc.','Apple Inc.','Microsoft','Sony','Razer','General Electric','Sony',
                                         'Microsoft','General Motors.','Check Point'],
                          'Ticker':['AAPL.MX','APC.DE','APC.F','MSFT','SNE','0700.HK','GE','6758.T','MSFT.BA','GM','CHKP'],
                          'Country':['MX','DE','F','US','US','HK','US','T','BA','US','US']})

df = pd.merge(df1,tickersdf,on=['CompanyName','Country'], how='outer')
df.loc[(df.CompanyName.isin(tickersdf.CompanyName))&df.Ticker_y.isna(), 'Ticker_y'] = 'hasalt'
df.loc[~(df.CompanyName.isin(tickersdf.CompanyName)),'Ticker_y'] = df.loc[~(df.CompanyName.isin(tickersdf.CompanyName))].Ticker_x

# rearrange data
df = df[df.CompanyName.isin(df1.CompanyName)].sort_values('CompanyName').reset_index(drop=True)
df.drop('Ticker_x', axis=1, inplace=True)
df = df.rename(columns={'Ticker_y':'Ticker'})
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is an *outer* merge of the two dataframes (see also [this excellent post about merging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101))

```
df2 = pd.merge(df1,tickersdf,on=['CompanyName','Country'], how='outer', sort=True)
```

followed by some post-processing for meeting your conditions - first drop the companies that are not present in `df1`:

```
df2 = df2.drop(df2[~df2.CompanyName.isin(df1.CompanyName.values)].index).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Note that I have assigned the result of the merge to another dataframe `df2`, so you can still access the original dataframe `df1` in this step.

Finally, create a new `Ticker` column based on `Ticker_x` and `Ticker_y`:

```
df2['Ticker'] = df2.apply (lambda r: r.Ticker_y if pd.isnull(r.Ticker_x) or r.Ticker_x == '' else r.Ticker_x, axis=1)
```